Override views field template with rendered value of another field
If I need override views field template with value of another field,
i write in
views-view-field-VIEW-NAME--DISPLAY-NAME--FIELD-NAME.html.twig
this code:
{{ view.field.ANOTHER-FIELD-NAME.original_value }}

It's works, but what if another field have option
Override the output of this field with custom text.
How to get this custom text in
views-view-field-VIEW-NAME--DISPLAY-NAME--FIELD-NAME.html.twig
?
